# formik with MUI Autocomplete | validation values return object

Tags: reactjs, object, material-ui, formik

My formik form submution values returns an object insted of the selected value.

The civility constant :

```
const civility: { id: number; name: string; }[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Mr' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Ms' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Miss' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Sir' },
];
```

The formik validation :

```
const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues,
    validationSchema,
    onSubmit: values => {
        console.log(values.civility);
        // Return Object
        // I want the specific name of the selected id

    },
});
```

The MUI Autocomplete field. The auctomple field set an oject instead of the name of the civility :

```
<Autocomplete
    id="civility"
    options={users.civility}
    getOptionLabel={option => option.name}
    onChange={(e, value) => formik.setFieldValue('civility', value)}
    renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <li {...props} key={option.id}>
            {option.name}
        </li>
    )}
    renderInput={params => (
        <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Civility"
        />
    )}
/>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:
onChange={(e, value) => formik.setFieldValue('civility', value.id)}